# Google Chrome Windows Reopens After Reopening It

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

When I leave a Chrome window open and shutdown Windows, when starting it again, the window reopens (with all the tabs). How can I disable this?

PS: I would also like to disable that Chrome opens up every tab again after I close the window. So when closing the window and opening it again that no tabs are open. Because I already select that Chrome should open ONLY chrome://apps on StartUp

PPS: Maybe the reopening of the whole window has something to do with Windows settings also?

---

**Note:** *This is not a duplicate as suggested above, since the problem also occurs when I just reopen Chrome without restarting Windows...*

Comment: Open chrome settings and scroll down to "On Startup" then tick "Open the New Tab Page"

Comment: I disagree with the above duplicate nomination. *This* question is about Chrome; *that* question is about Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to chrome setting

at the bottom of page see the on start up  option

set it to open the new tab page

save setting and restart chrome

hope it helps

Comment: Hah, if I knew it would be so simple. It is just a bit confusing, since there are three options to choose from (1) New tab (2) Open (all) last visited pages (3) Open a specific tab. I would have assumed, that (3) does ONLY open this specific tab and NOT also all the previously visited pages as well. But it looks like it does. Just a bit irritating...

Answer (score 1):

Try 'AdwCleaner' to remove all the unwanted PUP (Potential Unwanted Program) from your system. This will remove all the malware also and make your system clean.

Link to download:
https://downloads.malwarebytes.com/file/adwcleaner

Comment: _it will solve your problem if your problem is caused by any malware._

Comment: The problem was not caused by malware